# Como seleccionar un clon entre mas de 80 copias y modificar sus atributos

Tags: javascript, html, css, clone

he clonado un elemento en 80 copias pero necesito modificar unas 20 de esas copias para cambiar sus atributos, podrian decirme como hacerlo? No soy muy experto,y mi codigo seguramente tenga fallos,pero necesito algo de ayuda porque he probado varias cosas y no lo consigo.Os paso el link de mi trabajo:
https://codepen.io/Kawasaki93/pen/qBxwVbR

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/3883#3883).  Por favor, léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y elaborar buenas preguntas que obtengan mejores respuestas, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer un contador el cual por cada vez que se clone un elemento te vaya sumando un 1 allí ya tendrías cuantos elementos clonado tienes sean 80 o 100 y apartar de allí podrías generarlo por medio del ID un ejemplo seria por cada elemento clonado seria algo axial reflejado en el ID (ID1 -> ID2 -> ID3) ya con la posición de cada uno de los elementos puedes jugar con sus atributos o lo que desees saludos...

Comment: Buenas tardes,gracias por responder a la pregunta.Podrias ponerme un ejemplo con mi codigo para poder entender tu explicación?mil gracias y perdona por mi ignorancia.

Comment: Hola que tal basicamente lo que te respondio @VFG es lo que yo te explicaba.... ahora leo en la misma respuesta que le diste a el basicamente  si quieres que cambie un evento en un clon simplemente lo buscas o cuando estes encima de ese elemento haces que cambie el background un ejemplo seria algo como evento hover y listo para dicho elemento jejejeje espero poder ayudarte :D

Comment: en tu elemento clon_56 al darle al input se modifica el background en amarrillo podrias tomar ese mismo ejemplo y replicarlo donde desees :D espero poder ayudarte si tienes alguna duda solo comentame :D para ver si te ayudo je

Comment: Hola de nuevo moises,gracias por tu ayuda, necesito cambiar los clones de las ultimas filas a forma de hexagono, nose si con tu ultima respuestas te referias a encontrarlo utilizando un "inspeccionar elemento".Sabrias decirme que codigo poner en CSS para seleccionar uno de los clones?. He probado con .clon_3{ background: red;} por si funcionaba pero nada, tambien con .sunbed.clon_3{ } pero tampoco.Cual seria ?

Comment: en este caso lo tienes que hacer con jquery con las id... colocas algo como esto...

`$( #elem ).attr( "background", "red" ) ;`

Comment: hola moises de nuevo, actualmente necesito ayuda con el "localstorage".Podrias comentarme como puedo guardar el estado actual en el que dejo el plano para que cuando refresco el navegador vuelva a salir como lo deje? ; Ejemplo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raF32.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Sergio, lo mejor es poner un identificador único a cada clon. Puede ser el mismo `x` que usas para el `for`, o cualquier otro que te interese.

Prueba a cambiar, en el js,

```
$(".beach_wrapper").append($(".sunbed").first().clone(
));
```

por

```
$(".beach_wrapper").append($(".sunbed").first().clone(
).attr("id","clon_"+x));
```

En este caso, cada clon tendrá un `id` de la forma `id="clon_1"`, `id="clon_2"`, `id="clon_3"`, etc. Así después podrás modificar los que deseas a través de ese `id`.

Comment: Buenas tardes,primero que todo gracias por responder.Tu respuesta me ayuda bastante.He modificado el codigo como me comentastes pero ahora no consigo que me cambie por ejemplo el background de un clon.He probado a poner .sunbed.clon_1{} en CSS pero no me responde.perdona por mi ignorancia, podrias decirme el fallo? Mil gracias de nuevo ; 
 https://codepen.io/Kawasaki93/pen/NWyJdVx

Comment: Acabo de leer tu comentario y me imagino que desde entonces habrás modificado el código, porque ahora funciona. De todos modos yo siempre tendería a hacer cambios con `.addClass` mejor que con `.attr("style...)` porque así los cambios serán más fáciles. Pero cuidado en el `.dblclick` porque los `addClass` que haces están bien pero se van acumulando unos sobre otros. Deberías hacer un `.removeClass` del estilo anterior (`.data('actual-step')`) antes de poner el nuevo.

Comment: De nuevo mil gracias por tu ayuda,he intentado aplicar las correcciones que me comentastes y creo que lo consegui.Actualmente trato de eliminar los <form> de los clones que tengo como "desconectados" https://ibb.co/FgmdncC. No consigo dar con la tecla.He probado a introducir el id del form dentro del .desconectados pero nada.